# HTTP Error 500 when customer logins 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9.3.8

I'm experiencing ERROR 500 when I login as a customer. This only started happening after update to 1.9.3.8

I'm not able to find anything on the error logs from apache or magento log files.

Saw a similar problem with compilation ON here [HTTP ERROR 500 in checkout when compilation is on and user is logged](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217122/http-error-500-in-checkout-when-compilation-is-on-and-user-is-logged) but I have compilation OFF

The back end works without issues.

Anyone with similar issues?

---

So, a error_log was being created on magento dir with the following

```
Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getPasswordTimestamp() in /XXXXXXXXXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 530
```

So I checked if that function exists and it does.

```
USER@SERVER [~/XXXXXXXX/app]# grep -R "getPasswordTimestamp" .
./code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php:                Mage::helper('customer')->getPasswordTimestamp($this->_data['visitor_data']['customer_id']);
./code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php:    public function getPasswordTimestamp($customerId)
```

For some reason it is not able to call it.

Comment: are file permissions correct on /code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php ?

Answer (score 0):

On your staging / test environment, edit index.php of your Magento instance. Add the following after `define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Now reload the page, you should see the error.

Edit:
This error was common on SUPEE-10570, the function gets called twice which gives the 500 error

If you recently applied SUPEE-10570, please do the following

1. Check file permissions and ownership
2. Clear Magento cache and Magento file storage cache
3. Restart PHP Process to clear opcache